# Packaging MathJax library with Maven

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, mathjax, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a MathJax library next to my source files in one of my projects, which I build with Maven to get the WAR file for deployment. The problem is that the library has several thousand files which take forever to package.

After the inclusion of this library the build time went from less than a minute to more than 8 minutes. I've tried reducing the library as much as possible, but since I am using the library in a different way than most people, the usual "what more to reduce" tips cannot be applied and I need to keep the library mostly as is and where it is.

Is there some trick on Maven's side how to package such high number of small files, please?

Comment: Please show your pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise MathJax isn't a part of my POM, I have raw files which I use, next to my src files. It's a large project using both Java and JS modules - this is the JS part. The problem is when I build the package when I need to deploy. Or do you want to see the build config/profile?

Comment: You very likely don't need all of MathJax. Most files are pngs only necessary for extremely ancient browsers, see also https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-grunt-cleaner

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrautzberger, going to take a look at it!